# Why won't the jQuery slide effect work in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

```
$("#photoAlbum").on("mouseenter", ".imagecontainer", function () {
    $(this).find('.controlbar').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
}).on("mouseleave", ".imagecontainer", function () {
    $(this).find('.controlbar').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
});
```

`.controlbar` is hidden by default

The `.imagecontainer` div(s) is appended to #photoAlbum div after
an ajax request hence why I am using `.on()` and not just `.hover(function() {}, function(){})`

The HTML, drop-backdrop is absolutely positioned.

```
<div id="photoAlbum" class="tabcontent">

        <div id="drop-backdrop"> 
            <div class="text">Drag files here to upload</div> 
        </div> 
        <canvas id="drop-target"></canvas> 

<div class="imagecontainer"><div class="controlbar" style="visibility: hidden; "><img src="/TreeView/images/delete.png" width="16px" height="16px"></div><img src="/Content/photoAlbums/9/3/539695_t.jpg"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should load [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) library if you want your script to work

or use :

```
$("#photoAlbum").on("mouseenter", ".imagecontainer", function () {
    $(this).find('.controlbar').slideDown(1000);
}).on("mouseleave", ".imagecontainer", function () {
    $(this).find('.controlbar').slideUp(1000);
});
```

instead of `style="visibility: hidden; "` use `style="display:none; "`

Comment: @LaserBeak did you load jQuery in your page

Comment: @LaserBeak can you show us a part of your html code where you have `photoAlbum`

Comment: .slideDown() doesn't require jQuery UI does it?

Comment: @LaserBeak `slideDown()` does not require `jQuery UI`

Comment: @LaserBeak instead of `style="visibility: hidden;"` use `style="display:none;"`